# Scroll content inside the section with page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]
This is design I am trying to implement.There are two section A(Brown) and B(Green)(one below another).Both have fixed height of 400px and overflow is hidden.Both Section contains more than 10 image cards (staggered view) in it.Now desired result is when user scroll(page scroll) the contents inside the section A gets scrolled till end and then card below (section B ) moves up and again scrolls the contents inside the section B.

So the in short if user scroll firstly the contents inside the first section should move up and reaches to end of section.Then the second section should move up to previous position of first section and again content inside should move up.This should happen for each section present in page.

Note:There can't be two scroll (i.e one scroll for each section and one for the whole page).It scroll should be managed by one scroll.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Can you post your code i.p.o. those images?

Comment: @Franco what is i.p.o ?

Comment: In place of the images

Comment: @MarutiNandan add your code or make a fiddle